# Adding signature to jar file prevents it from being loaded

Tags: java, jar, code-signing, signing, jar-signing

I am having the problem that adding a second signature to a .jar file causes trouble in combination with code that only has one of them.

Background: We have an [application](http://stendhalgame.org) that is signed with an expired certificate. It has a starter that can update itself by downloading new versions of .jar files and placing them in front of the existing ones onto the classpath.

We got a new certificate and sign the new starter and the updates with both keys. Unfortunately the old applications is now refusing to startup:

- the starter (signed with the old cert) builds up the classpath.
- then it calls a method from a class ("Stendhal") jar that is signed with both certs
- this method loads a class ("LogUncaughtExceptionHandler") from a jar which is only signed with the old cert.

SecurityException: class "games.stendhal.client.LogUncaughtExceptionHandler"'s signer information does not match signer information of other classes in the same package

Comment: The only solution we've found is to remove the original signature and sign with the new one.

Answer (score 0):

Could you not arrange to also download a new version of the jar with `LogUncaughtExceptionHandler`, also signed with the new cert?  If not, I don't think you're going to find a suitable resolution to this issue.